# MYSQL mysql-slow.log rolling file

Tags: mysql, logging

The file mysql-slow.log on my server got truncated. I am wondering where is the rolling file or where is the old compressed file ? or need to be specified in the setting file to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually the case where logrotate is setup, however the logrotate's `postrotate` script doesn't have the required access database to run `mysqladmin flush`.

Check your logrotate logs. If you look in `/proc/$(pidof mysqld)/fd` you'll see a link to the deleted slow query log. You can copy this entry to another file to save this as a copy of the slow query log.

Comment: What is the solution then to automate this?

Comment: give `mysqladmin flush` access to the database through a configuration file containing the password, or a unix socket authenticated user on which the postrotate script runs.